# Datagridview doesn't refresh

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I'm  new to visual C# and I created a local database and added a datagridview that shows the contents of the database. The problem is that the datagridview doesn't refresh whenever I add something to the database. It only refreshes once I run my application again.

I tried changing the connectionstring from this:

```
SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Florence\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Quality.sdf");
```

to this:

```
SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.QualityConnectionString);
```

But then, the datagridview refreshes but the data doesn't store into the database. 
Here is my insert statement:

```
try
{
    SqlCeCommand exeSql = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO [Read](Date,temperature,ph,conductivity,dissolvedOxygen) VALUES (@date,@tem,@ph,@con,@dis)", cn);
    exeSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", lblTime.Text);
    exeSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tem", 1.5);
    exeSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ph", 1.2);
    exeSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@con", 1.5);
    exeSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dis", 1.5);
    cn.Open();
    exeSql.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
finally
{
    MessageBox.Show("Query added!");
    cn.Close();
    this.readTableAdapter.Fill(this.qualityDataSet.Read);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by the sounds of it, it seems like you don't quite understand how the DataGrid works. First of all the basic functionality of a DataGrid is to create columns and rows to display a set of data which is passed to it.

So when you are doing your select statement you select out a set of data and pass it to the DataGrid. However at this point the DataGrid isn't interacting with the query anymore, and the query isn't retrieving anymore data.

So in order to have the DataGrid be refreshed to show the new data, you have a few options, however the simplest I can think of for your case is to **simply requery the data and pass in the new dataset that you retrieve.** Then call one of the helper functions (I believe its **.Refresh** or **.Update**) to tell the DataGrid to reload itself with the new data it has received.

Comment: I tried using datagridview1.refresh(); and datagridview1.update(); but it's still the same. Nothing changes. Any tips please? Thank you very much.